# how to access rowindex from another layout tablelayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablelayout

I need to access and changue color  data in rows.
I need to access the rows that are clicked and change their color

TableLAyout.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Views.MarcadoXLoteActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_border"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView73"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView73" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView26x"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-34dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spinner3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_arrow_drop_down_24" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarM"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:title="  Marcado de Avances Por Lote"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black">


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="798dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#DEF1DE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbarM">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNomMarcado"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="     CIMENTACION"
            android:textColor="#11B818"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView72"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Manzana"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView73"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
        android:text="Rango de Lotes"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMan"
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_border"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView72"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView72" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView26"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-34dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerMan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinnerMan"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spinnerMan"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_arrow_drop_down_24" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlMarcado"
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="789dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner3">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:background="#51B435"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="DESCRIPCIÓN"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="PRECIO


                CONTRATISTA"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTarjetaML"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="015004001"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="015004001"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="015004001"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="015004001"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="015004001"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </TableRow>




    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnguardarmercado"
        android:layout_width="562dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="352dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="352dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_gray"
        android:text="GUARDAR AVANCE"
        android:textColor="#FFFEFE"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tlMarcado" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_border"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView71"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spinner3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView88"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-34dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spinner4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_arrow_drop_down_24" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView71"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:text="Al"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView73" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Second Layout rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescML"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tableborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="FAB. DE REGISTRO PLUBIAL" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrecioML"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tableborder"
        android:text=" $129.00" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blueM"
        android:padding="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blueM"
        android:padding="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blueM"
        android:padding="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blueM"
        android:padding="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#2A42C6"
        android:padding="6dp" />

</TableRow>
```

Code to access row with click and changue color:

```
 private fun marcartablerocolor() {
        val tableLayout = findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.tlMarcado)
        val tablaMarcados2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_layoutmarcado, tableLayout, false) as TableRow

        for (rowIndex in 0 until tablaMarcados2.childCount) {
            val tableRow = tablaMarcados2.getChildAt(rowIndex) as TableRow
            for (cellIndex in 0 until tableRow.childCount) {
                val cellView = tableRow.getChildAt(cellIndex)
                cellView.setOnClickListener {
                    // Handle click event
                    onTableCellClicked(rowIndex, cellIndex)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

changue color function:

```
private fun onTableCellClicked(rowIndex: Int, cellIndex: Int) {
        val tablaMarcados: TableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tlMarcado)

        val verde = resources.getColor(R.color.greenM)
        val clickedColor = resources.getColor(R.color.blueM)

        val tableRow = tablaMarcados.getChildAt(rowIndex) as TableRow
        val cellView = tableRow.getChildAt(cellIndex)

        if (cellView is TextView) {
            val cellValue = cellView.text.toString()
            val currentColor = (cellView.background as ColorDrawable).color

            if (currentColor == clickedColor){
                cellView.setBackgroundColor(verde)
            }

            if (currentColor == verde){
                cellView.setBackgroundColor(clickedColor)
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is error.
I already looked for how to do it and I couldn't, could you help me

***I'm solved with this function***

```
private fun marcartablerocolor() {
        val tableLayout = findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.tlMarcado)

        for (rowIndex in 0 until tableLayout.childCount) {
            val tableRow = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex) as TableRow

            tableRow.setOnClickListener {
                val rowIndex = tableLayout.indexOfChild(tableRow)
                // Handle row click event with rowIndex
                onTableRowClicked(rowIndex)
            }

            for (cellIndex in 0 until tableRow.childCount) {
                val cellView = tableRow.getChildAt(cellIndex)
                cellView.setOnClickListener {
                    val rowIndex = tableLayout.indexOfChild(tableRow)
                    // Handle cell click event with rowIndex and cellIndex
                    onTableCellClicked(rowIndex, cellIndex)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```